# Does unix utility tail read through the whole file?

Tags: design-patterns, filter, grep, cgi, tail

I used tail utility with option -f to watch one of my log files. My CGI program always sent only the last 40 lines of the log file to my webpage, where I can monitor the log real time and with audible notifications. Now I would like to send only the last 40 lines which meet some conditions, eg. matches to any pattern. I think I have to use grep, but how can I select only the last 40 matching lines? Do I have to use "tail" twice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tac file | grep "your regexp here" | head -40 | tac

time (grep bar file | tail -40) >/dev/null
real    0m15.472s
user    0m15.316s
sys     0m0.172s

time (tac file | grep bar | head -40 | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.146s
user    0m0.184s
sys     0m0.004s

time (tac file | grep -m40 bar | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Discovered an alias `grep="grep -P"`, so that's clean grep results:

```
time ("grep" bar file | tail -40) >/dev/null

real    0m1.316s
user    0m1.164s
sys     0m0.172s

time (tac file | "grep" bar | head -40 | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.071s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.092s

time (tac file | "grep" -m40 bar | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.056s
```

Comment: You're missing the extra `| tac` at the end to put the lines back into their original order and the only way for this to make any kind of sense would be if you replaced `grep "your regexp here" | head -40` with `grep -m 40 "your regexp here"` so grep wouldn't have to search the whole file but then you're still adding a `tac` of the whole file and a `tac` of 40 lines at the end so idk if it'd actaully improve performance over `grep .. | tail`.

Comment: Change `cat file | grep 1000` to `grep 1000 file`. You NEVER need to use `cat` to open a file for another tool - google UUOC. You don't say how the large the file is or many times `1000` appears in it. Also, did you run each command 3 times before collecting stats to remove caching issues? If `1000` appears frequently in the input file and the input file is large then you should see a significant performance improvement of `grep -m 40 1000 file` vs `grep 1000 file | head -40`.

Comment: I know about the caching file issue, so I tried three times, yes.

Comment: OK then get rid of the UUOC and try again and tell us about the input file - size, how often 1000 appears in it, etc.

Comment: UUOC doesn't affect performance, so it's a matter of taste. The size is about 80mb, it's about 1.5mln of lines, 1000 appears 4.5k times.

Comment: Of course it affects performance - it's an extra process and a pipe. I tested it myself and posted the results in my answer. As expected it's faster to do `grep | tail` than `tac | grep | head | tac` because both pipelines are greping through every line of the file but the latter is adding 2 more processes and pipelines. I do think `tac | grep -m 40 | tac` could be faster for some distributions of the searched regexp even thought it wasn't for my test case since grep will stop after the 40th match instead of searching the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep condition file | tail -40
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to show some sample input and expected output (NOT 40+ lines worth though).

wrt the performance discussion in the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220727/1745001: On a 1M line file where "bar" appears 1,000 times and every other line is just "foo" as created by this script:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print (i%1000 ? "foo" : "bar")}' > file
```

Here is the third-run timing in bash 4.3.33 under cygwin:

```
$ time (grep bar file | tail -40) >/dev/null
real    0m0.050s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.045s

$ time (tac file | grep bar | head -40 | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.061s
sys     0m0.107s

$ time (tac file | grep -m 40 bar | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.080s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.090s
```

On a 100M file created by:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=100000000;i++) print (i%1000 ? "foo" : "bar")}' > file
```

I get:

```
$ time (grep bar file | tail -40) >/dev/null
real    0m1.014s
user    0m0.841s
sys     0m0.202s

$ time (tac file | grep bar | head -40 | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m1.154s
user    0m1.262s
sys     0m0.248s

$ time (tac file | grep -m 40 bar | tac) >/dev/null
real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s
```

All exactly as expected. For the first 2 the grep is doing exactly the same processing in searching the whole file and THAT is what drives most of the duration, with the only difference in workload being `tail` vs `tac+pipe+head+pipe+tac`, while with the 3rd one the grep is doing much less work since it exits after the 40th match and so the overall pipeline is faster.

Comment: When I reproduce your experiment, I get equal numbers on both grep&tail vs tac&grep&head&tac. But when I'm applying this to real data tac way is much faster. Maybe the generated file isn't large enough?

Comment: Added three zeros to awk generation script and got tac performance much better

Comment: Are you sure you're enclosing the time args in brackets so the timing is for the whole pipeline? When you run time on a raw pipeline the results are unspecified so your results might be comparing the timing of `tac file` vs `grep bar file` instead of comparing the whole pipelines.

Comment: Tried both enclosed and not, no difference. Also tried grepping foo (mistake?), the difference gets bigger.

Comment: I didn't want to wait for results from a 1,000M line file so I tried with a 100M lines file and got exactly the expected results again, see above. Do you have any logical explanation for why `tac file | grep bar | head -40 | tac` would be faster then `grep bar file | tail -40`? I just can't understand logically why it would be and of course the results I'm getting are saying it isn't.

Comment: I think head just closes the pipe, so grep receives SIGPIPE and exits without reading the whole file. The strange thing is why `grep | tail` and `tac | grep | head | tac` do not differ on your computer, the latter is 2-3 times faster on my laptop cygwin and ~100 times faster on an ubuntu server (but `tac | grep -m | tac` is still the optimal way)

Comment: If head closes the pipe and that stops grep then the results for `grep | head -40 | tac` should be almost identical to `grep -m 40 | tac` - is that what you are seeing? I'd be interested to see your results for the same example I gave above if you can be bothered running the scripts and editing your answer.

Comment: Ah I see you had been using `grep -P`, that'd certainly slow things down as the perl regexp engine is immensely slow and unfortunately not smart enough to use the regular regexp engine when your specific regexp isn't using Perl extensions. For the other part - I guess the head must be closing the pipe and the rest is probably down to buffering. You live and learn...

Comment: Thx, interestingly I have never heard of this "tac" utility till now.